# Enable VncServer 6.2.1 ARMv6 experimental capture mode by command line

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, vnc-server

I'm not able to enable the Raspberry Pi's VNC capture mode from the command line.
ExperimentalRaspiCapture mode allows you to remotely view videos running.

If not enabled, you cannot watch videos. As my application has disabled the raspbian graphical mode, I only have operations from the command line and I do not have access to the internet on them, only local network.

I did tests on an alternative raspberry and in graphical mode I enabled this option according to the tutorial on page [vncserver experimental direct capture mode missing](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=208682) and it worked for me, but I have several raspberries and enabling it by command line is my best option at the moment, but I can't enable it.

I already tried the tutorial on the page:
[How do I get VNC access to Kano OS working correctly?](https://community.kano.me/t/how-do-i-get-vnc-access-to-kano-os-working-correctly/324)
But it did not work.

Any idea? Has anyone managed to do this?
Thanks.

**Use vnc version**: *VNC (R) Server 6.2.1 (r32538) ARMv6*

**I use the raspberry**:
*Linux raspberrypi 4.14.34-v7 *

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the problem. I wasn't doing it right. I have to change the file in the root user and then restart the serviced. ;)

Edit the config file '/root/.vnc/config.d/vncserver-x11'
adding the following:

```
CaptureTech=raspi
ExperimentalRaspiCapture=1
ServerPreferredEncoding=JPEG
```

and then restarted:

```
sudo systemctl restart vncserver-x11-serviced
```